# Reformulating the maximal margin classifier optimization problem

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm

Ok, so I've been trying to read up on how SVM's work and started with maximal margin classifiers. At page $132$ in ESL (Elements of Statistical Learning) the authors "reformulates" the optimization problem but I can't seem to understand what they are doing from $(4.47)$ to $(4.48)$. Does anyone know?

Here is an excerpt:

[image: Excerpt]

Edit: I guess, what I don't understand is why we can arbitrarly set the magnitude of beta to $\frac1M$. What does a positively scaled multiple mean in this case? Just a multiple larger than $0$?

Comment: cross-posted (later) at https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/453752/232706

Answer (score 2):

If $(\beta, \beta_0)$ satisfies the inequality $(4.47)$, then for any positive $k$, $k>0$, $(k\beta, k\beta_0)$ would satisfies the inequality as well.

Also, $(\hat{\beta}, \hat{\beta}_0)=\left( \frac{\beta}{M\|\beta\|}, \frac{\beta_0}{M\|\beta\|} \right)$ satiesfies the inequlity as well since

$$y_i(x_i^T\hat{\beta}+\hat{\beta}_0)=\frac{y_i}{M\|\beta\|}(x_i^T\beta+\beta_0) \ge \frac{M\|\beta|}{M\|\beta\|}=1=M\|\hat{\beta}\|$$

Let's find $\hat{\beta}$ and $\hat{\beta}_0$ directly. Note that $\hat{\beta}$  satisfies the property that $\|\hat{\beta}\|=\frac1M.$

Hence we let $\|\hat{\beta}\|$ to be $\frac1M$, hence reducing the inequality to be

$$y_i(x_i^T\hat{\beta} + \hat{\beta}_0) \ge 1$$
$$\|\hat{\beta}\|=\frac1M$$

We want to maximize $M$, hence, we minimize $\frac1M$, which is equivalent to minimizing $\frac12\|\hat{\beta}\|^2$.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Okay, I understand the scaling part now. However I still don't get how we can just set beta to equal one over M. Isn't M what we want to optimize which should change between iterations of optimization?

Comment: Yes, I shouldn't have used the word "fix".  I have tried to improve the answer. Yes, $M$ changes if you use an iterative algorithm to find $M$.